# Equivalent property for websphere purge policy in tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, websphere

There is a property called "Purge policy" in websphere datasource setting ,is there an equivalent property in tomcat that can be used.

Comment: And this property does what, exactly?

Comment: purge policy-used to purge the  stale connection .

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from their [connection pool documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Common_Attributes), you could approximate the Purge Policy behavior with testOnReturn (or testOnBorrow), but this will incur additional overhead in that it will apply to every connection request, rather than in response to an observed stale connection.  It looks like they give you a validationInterval property to cut down on some of the overhead, but again there appears to be a trade-off in that it could result in delaying the response to an identified stale connection if my understanding is correct.